# How do these characters escape from the chopper?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In the *X-Men: Apocalypse* movie, when Stryker captures some mutants (Mystique, Hank and don't remember who else) along with Moira and takes them with him in his chopper they are kept in a cabin (within the chopper) where they can't use their mutant powers. In an attempt to rescue them Jean, Nightcrawler and Scott teleport inside that cabin and get stuck as now even they can't use their powers.

But later, somehow these three get out of the cabin and are not part of the prisoners Stryker has kept in his cell. How do Jean, Nightcrawler and Scott escape from Stryker’s chopper?

I know Jean can control the guards' minds and prevent the guards from noticing them but since she can't use her powers within this chopper cabin, I assumed when the chopper lands and they open the cabin, Stryker and his guards should have noticed these extra mutants (though this scene where they land the chopper and open the cabin is not shown in the movie).

Answer (score 3):

While it might seem like a plot hole, there's a quite logical explanation. Two actually.

### Teleport

The variation with teleportation hinges on exact timing and a view out of a window, but it can be done. Nightcrawler can only teleport within the cage, as seen in an earlier scene where he fights Angel. He just can't get out. However, when the cage was open, he was easily able to get in.

To get Quicksilver, Mystique et al out of the chopper, Stryker and his men would have to open the door and therefore disable the field. If Nightcrawler can see out the window, he can port out the second the field is disabled.

### Telepathy

Jean says she can't reach out of the chopper. However, if we apply the logic from the earlier scene where Angel fights Nightcrawler inside an enabled Field and uses his powers, she can use her powers inside the field.

So the second the door to the chopper's holding area opens and the field is disabled, she is certainly able to reach the men's minds. And even if the field is still intact, she can still reach minds inside the field. So if a soldier comes in, all she needs is a head inside a field and she can do whatever mind tricks she wants.